# Assigning a parent element for each <slot> in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component, say `my-component`, which is like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I use the component:

```
<my-component>
    <p>This is paragraph 1 </p>
    <p>This is paragraph 2 </p>
</my-component>
```

The produced html becomes this (as it normally should):

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>This is paragraph 1 </p>
        <p>This is paragraph 2 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But instead, I am looking for a way to produce something like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>This is paragraph 1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>This is paragraph 2 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I associate one `inner` div with each of the `slot` elements?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to use a render function instead of a template. Doing that, you can examine the content of the default slot and wrap the contents as needed.

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("container",{
  template: "#container-template",
  render(h){
    // filter out things like carriage returns, spaces, etc
    const content = this.$slots.default.filter(c => !c.text)
    // build a list of wrapped content
    const wrapped = content.map(c => h('div', {attrs: {class:"inner"}}, [c]))
    // render the component
    return h("div", {attrs:{class:"outer"}}, wrapped)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <container>
    <p>This is paragraph 1 </p>
    <p>This is paragraph 2 </p>
  </container>
</div>
```

Comment: Bert, not that I don't appreciate your answer, but I am looking for a simpler solution rather than using the render method. Is it possible to tackle the problem using named slots? And of course, thanks for your answer. For the time being, I am upvoting the answer. If I don't get any other solution, I will accept the answer :)