# Multiple child component with single root element in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is how my child component looks like:

```
<template>
<div class="body">
    <div class="block">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'block'
    }
</script>
```

From my parent component, I want to do something like this:

```
<div>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
</div>
```

...but without the surrounding root `.body` div element being replicated each time.

I want something like this:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="block">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of this:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="block">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
        <div class="block">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
</div>
<div class="body">
        <div class="block">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You want the .body class not be repeated? Or you do not want a starting element tag for your .vue templates?

Comment: @hamzox question updated

Comment: Why not simply get rid of `.body` from component file, just keep `.block`, and use `.body`, to wrap declared components, in parent component ?

Comment: @BelminBedak Imagine a situation where I need to use a lot of `.body` div element. How can I reduce the usage?

Comment: Then make a component for .body div as well.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get It.

Comment: Even if I separately created a component for `.body` div, I would still have to load that component for each of my blocks. Say I have created `<mbody>` component, then I'd have to do this: `<mbody><block></block></mbody>`. Wouldn't this be better if I told my `block` component to automatically wrap a `.body` div around it? So that I can just do this: `<block>Foobar</block>`

Comment: Okaay! Got it. I am updating my answer.

Comment: It looks like I had the same problem a few months ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909483/assigning-a-parent-element-for-each-slot-in-vue I couldn't accept Bert's answer because it was too complicated. Is there a simpler solution for situations like this?

Answer (score 3):

From your question this is what I understand.
Make your single file vue component like this.

```
<template>
    <div class="block">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        export default {
            name: 'block'
        }
    </script>
```

Your parent div:

```
<div class="body">
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
    <block></block>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  tag as your root tag. I used to do this and works well.

It is like:

```
<template>
 <literal>
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
 </literal>
</template>
```